# C++: Recv blocking forever despite data being sent

Tags: c++, sockets

I have two threads running in my program. One is sending data to the other. The socket is connecting fine on both threads, and the receiving thread is accepting the connection. However, once the recv is called, it just sits there blocking as if its getting nothing in, despite the fact that the other thread is sending.

Sending thread

```
send(orig_sock, buf, BUFSIZ,0);
printf("Client sending chunk\n");
```

The printf manages to get displayed.

Receiving thread

```
printf("START ACCEPTING\n");
        if ((new_sock = accept( orig_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &clnt_adr, &clnt_len)) < 0) {
            perror("accept error");
            close(orig_sock);
            return NULL;
        }
        printf("PASS ACCEPT\n");
        if ( fork( ) == 0 ) {                        // Generate a CHILD
            printf("FORK\n");
            len=recv(new_sock, buf, BUFLEN,0 );
                printf("message received");
                receiveBuffer.push(*p);
                //write(new_sock, buf, len);           
                //if ( buf[0] == '.' ) break;          

            printf("Did not receive message\n");
            close(new_sock);                         
            return NULL;
        } else
            close(new_sock);
```

All the messages up untill "FORK" are being diplayed, and the thrad hangs on the recv call.  buf is defined as `static char buf[BUFSIZ];`
Any reason why the recv call would not be seeing any data?

Comment: What does `send()` return in this case?

Comment: `send` and `accept` uses the same socket?

Comment: why are you using sockets for inter-thread communication? There are more efficient ways to pass data between threads of the same process.

Answer (score 3):

```
send(orig_sock, buf, BUFSIZ,0);
```

and

```
if ((new_sock = accept( orig_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &clnt_adr, &clnt_len)) < 0) {
```

don't make sense together. Either `orig_sock` is connected or it is listening. Not both. Your lack of error checking on the `send()` is masking this error.

You can't send to a listening socket.

Comment: I modified my code to start printing out the return value of send. It looks like there is something being sent (orig_sock is defined differently in both the code snippets).
New code
    `int bl = send(orig_sock, buf, BUFSIZ,0);`
    `printf("Client sending chunk: %d\n", clientNum, bl);`
Output
    `Client sending chunk: 8192`
    `Client sending chunk: -1`
So, it tries to send two different chunks. The first one looks like it sends, and the second one doesn't.

Comment: Use `errno` (or `WSAGetLastError()` on Windows) to find out why `send()` fails. But you definitely cannot `send()` to the same socket that is `accept()`'ing connections. You have to `send()` to the socket that was `accept()`'ed.

Comment: @ToxicSockWarrior That printf() can't possibly print what you claim it prints. Clearly that isn't the real code.